# リクエストパラメータに変数の値を入れた URL を生成したい

Tags: java

リクエストパラメータに変数の値を入れたいと思います。
下記のコードに変数を使ってxのところに"00001"、yのところに1234が入るようにしたいです。
どういう書き方をすればよろしいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
String userId = "00001"
int cost = 1234;

http://localhost:8080/servlet/test?userId=x&cost=y
```

Comment: `userId` は文字列型のようですが、数字（0~9）しか含まないと前提して大丈夫ですか？ 任意の文字を含み得る場合は、考慮しなければいけない点があります。

Comment: 承認機能について知っておられますかね? 一番役に立った回答は承認できます。(今まで使っておられなかったので尋ねさせていただきたくて)

Comment: 承認機能について最近知りました。回答の左側にあるグレーのチェックマークをクリックするのですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL文字列に固定な部分と変数を連結すればいいと思います。
例:
string url = "http://localhost:8080/servlet/test?userId=" + userId + "&cost=" + cost

Answer (score 6):

リクエスト URL を構築するには、[Apache URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) をおすすめします。

```
String url = new URIBuilder("http://localhost:8080/servlet/test")
        .setParameter("userId", userId)
        .setParameter("cost", String.valueOf(cost))
        .build().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

＋演算子を使った方法はすでに説明されていますので別の方法を書きたいと思います。

このコードでは、[java.lang.String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)メソッドを使っています。

```
String format = "http://localhost:8080/servlet/test?userId=%s&cost=%d";
String url = String.format(format, userId, cost);//プレースフォルダに値を入れる
```

1. 書式指定文字列を作る。`%s`や`%d`はプレースフォルダと言い、値が入る場所になる。
2. `String.format`メソッドの第一引数に書式指定文字列を入れる。
3. 第二引数以降で値を入れる。